# How to load a wikipedia page in Java

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to a wikipedia page on each US city.  Since I don't know the actual URL, I do a search and load the first result.  The URL signature to do this is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?go=Go&search=New+York%2C+NY

However, it doesn't get anything back, here is my code:

```
String curWikiURL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?go=Go&search="+URLEncoder.encode("New York, NY", "UTF-8");;
Scanner scanner = null;
URLConnection connection = null;
connection =  new URL(curWikiURL).openConnection();
scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
content = scanner.next();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
```

Comment: It is against Wikipedia policies to use the crawler bots like that. You probably will be blocked rather soon. Unless it is not a crawler.

Comment: I just try to read it once to gather some data to do a study, so there isn't any web-crawling.  It's more like I am automating a task that otherwise I would have to done manually.

Comment: Are you going to need the information in HTML or use the JSON API could be an option ?

Comment: I don't need the information in HTML.  How would I search for a city if I don't know the exact URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do all the connection and stuff JSoup library can handle all these.Check out below

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm ";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup
            .connect(url).followRedirects(false).timeout(60000).get();
    org.jsoup.select.Elements elements = ((org.jsoup.nodes.Document) document)
            .body().children();
for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm
```

This is how you use MediaWiki APIs.

Check here for more details - https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page